# ng-repeat with ng-if causing Object.noSuchMethod exception

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to write an ng-repeat, where some of the elements are there and some aren't, like this:

```dart
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems" ng-if="locationState == menuItem.displayWhen" 
      ng-class="{'menu-item-divided': isCurrentPage(menuItem.routeName), 'pure-menu-selected': isCurrentPage(menuItem.routeName)}">
      <a href="#{{menuItem.routeName}}" 
      ng-click="menuItem.whenClicked()">{{menuItem.pageName}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But when I do it like that, it tries to access a `menuItem` getter in my component. If I put the ng-if on the `a` element, though, it works fine. Shouldn't `menuItem` be in scope for directives on the element I am using `ng-repeat` on?

Comment: Use a filter instead of `ng-if`

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Not a duplicate, because this is an angular.dart question, not an angular.js question.

Comment: Oh, well, if you say so. I believe the core of the problem as well as the solution are still the same though.

Comment: If the solution in the linked answer doesn't work for your problem add a comment and the question can be reopened.

Comment: Making a filter does work, but it also is an unfortunate solution. I won't reuse this filter, and instead of one short line on an element I need 1. a new file 2. call that filter method from the repeat 3. import and bind the file when all I want to do is check if `x == y`!